# Finding $|A|^2+|B|^2$ if $A=\text{adj} (B)-B^T$ and $B=\text{adj} (A)-A^T$

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Consider two $3\times3$ matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfying $A=\text{adj} (B)-B^T$ and $B=\text{adj} (A)-A^T$ (where $C^T$ denotes transpose of matrix $C$). If $A$ is a non-singular matrix, then find $AB$ and $|A|^2+|B|^2$ (where $|C|$ denotes determinant of matrix $C$). Also, find $|\text{adj} (2B^{-1})|$.

Given, $A=\text{adj} (B)-B^T$. Taking transpose on both sides, I get $A^T=(\text{adj} B)^T-B$. Putting $B=\text{adj} (A)-A^T$ in it, I get, $A^T=(\text{adj}B)^T-\text{adj(A)}+A^T\implies\text{adj} A=(\text{adj} B)^T$. Taking determinant on both sides, I get $|A|^2=|B|^2$ (because $|\text{adj} C|=|C|^{n-1}$ where $n$ is the order of $C$ and $|C|=|C^T|)$.

Also, since $A$ is non-singular, if I divide $B=\text{adj} (A)-A^T$ by $|A|$, I get $\dfrac B{|A|} = A^{-1} - \dfrac{A^T}{|A|} \implies  \dfrac{B + A^T}{|A|} = A^{-1}$. Taking determinant on both sides, I get $\dfrac{|B+A^T|}{|A|^3} = \dfrac1{|A|} \implies |B + A^T| = |A|^2$ (because $|kC| = k^n|C|$, where $k$ is any constant (here $\frac1{|A|}$) and $n$ is order of matrix $C$. Also, $|C^{-1}|=\frac1{|C|}$).

Not able to proceed next.

EDIT: After @Upayan De's answer, $|B|=8$.

Now, $\text{adj}(kC)=k^{n-1}\text{adj}C$, where $k$ is a constant and $n$ is the order of matrix $C$.

So, $\text{adj}(2B^{-1})=4\text{adj}(B^{-1})$.

So, $|\text{adj}(2B^{-1})|=|4\text{adj}(B^{-1})|=64|\text{adj}(B^{-1})|$.

Now, $|\text{adj}(B^{-1})|=(|\text{adj}B|)^{-1}=(|B|^2)^{-1}=1/64$.

So, $|\text{adj}(2B^{-1})|=1$

Comment: In the first line, instead of $3*3$, I want to write $3$ corss $3$, how to do that?

Comment: Use \times as follows: $3 \times 3$

Comment: Also, see my edits for \text{adj}. You need to use brackets to make this part clear.

Comment: @ThePointer thanks.

Comment: Use brackets with adj so that people can tell what matrices you're referring to.

Comment: @ThePointer ok, 1 min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking transpose of the first equation, we have, $$A^T = (adj(B))^T - B$$ Substituting that in the second equation we have, $$\begin{aligned}B &= \text{adj}(A) - (\text{adj}(B))^T + B \\ (\text{adj}(B))^T &= \text{adj}(A) \\ \text{adj}(B^T) &= \text{adj}(A) \qquad \text{...(1)} \end{aligned}$$ Taking adjoint of both sides, and using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vej0dRB1MGw) result, $$\begin{aligned} \text{adj(adj}(B^T)) &= \text{adj(adj}(B)) \\ |B^T|B^T &= |A|A\end{aligned}$$ Again, taking determinant of (1),$$|B^T|^2=|A|^2 \implies |B^T|=\pm|A|$$ Hence, we can conclude, $$B^T=\pm A$$
However, $A=-B^T$ on substituting in the first equation, gives $\text{adj}(B)=0 \implies |B|=0$

But $B$ is non-singular $\implies B^T=A$

Hence, from first equation, $$\begin{aligned}2A&=\text{adj}(A^T) \\ |2A| &= |\text{adj}(A^T)| \\ 8|A| &= |A^T|^2 \\ |A|&=|B|=8\end{aligned}$$ Therefore, $$|A|^2 + |B|^2 = 64 + 64 = 128$$

**EDIT**: My apologies for overlooking the other subparts of the question initially. Now since you have already worked out $|adj(2B^{-1})|$, I'll just post the answer AB

Post-multiplying first equation by $B$, we have, $$\begin{aligned}AB &= (\text{adj}(B))B - B^TB \\ AB &= |B|I - AB \\ 2AB &= 8I \\ AB &= 4I \end{aligned}$$ Hope that's all :-)

Comment: +1. Thanks. Can you also comment about $AB$ and $|\text{adj}(2B^{-1})|$?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What do you want to know about them?

Comment: The question also asks to find $AB$ and $|\text{adj}(2B^{-1})|$. If I put $A=B^T$ in $AB$, I get $B^TB$. Now, this can be equal to $I$ if $B$ were an orthogonal matrix. But that's not the case. So, how can we find $AB$? Also, if I were to find $|\text{adj}(B^{-1})|$, I would have written $|B|^{-2}$ but how to find $|\text{adj}(2B^{-1})|$?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't notice that. $|adj(2B^{-1})|$ is not a problem, but are you sure the question asks for $AB$ and not $|AB|$?

Comment: I think I got $|\text{adj}(2B^{-1})|$. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Yes, the question asks $AB$ and not $|AB|$.

Comment: ok, sure. By the way, I have edited my post.

Comment: @aarbee I've edited the answer. Hope that solves it.

Comment: Thank you so much.